# How I can Assign specific values to the array?

Tags: c, arrays, variable-assignment

How can I store all the divisors in the array a ??

this program shows the divisors of a number and then decide if it's prime and/or perfect ... The problem is I can't store the values of the divisors in the array a.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   int DivCount=0,n,i,j,a[100],sum=0;

    printf("Please Enter the Number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    if (n%i==0){
            a[i-1]=i;
              DivCount++;
                }

    printf("\nThe Number Has %d divisors : ",DivCount);
    for(i=0;i<DivCount;i++)
    printf("%d\t",a[i]);

    if (DivCount==2)
        printf("\nThe Number is Prime");
    else
        printf("\nThe Number is NOT Prime");

     for(i=0;i<DivCount;i++)
        sum+=a[i];
     printf("\nThe Sum of the divisors is :%d",sum);

    if (sum==n)
        printf("\nThe Number is Perfect");
    else
        printf("\nThe Number is NOT Perfect");

    return 0;
}
```

for example (n=6) the array should be = {1,2,3,6}

Comment: `a[i-1]=i;` is major problem. Use another variable for array indexing and thus keep count of divisors. For ex: `a[divisor_count++] = i;`

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2)  do not omit optional braces '{' and '}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   int DivCount=0,n,i,j,a[100],sum=0;

    printf("Please Enter the Number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    if (n%i==0){

        //a[i-1]=i;  <--- check this
        a[DivCount]=i;
        DivCount++;
    }

    printf("\nThe Number Has %d divisors : ",DivCount);
    for(i=0;i<DivCount;i++)
    printf("%d\t",a[i]);

    if (DivCount==2)
        printf("\nThe Number is Prime");
    else
        printf("\nThe Number is NOT Prime");

     for(i=0;i<DivCount;i++)
        sum+=a[i];
     printf("\nThe Sum of the divisors is :%d",sum);

    if (sum==n)
        printf("\nThe Number is Perfect");
    else
        printf("\nThe Number is NOT Perfect");

    return 0;
}
```